# Add items to chosen and have them selected on entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using some code from an input which adds items to a `jquery chosen` select and this works OK. However, what I need to do is once a user adds them to the list them have them selected and not have to use the dropdown to select them. Is this possible with this plugin?

Many thanks

js

```
$(function() {
   $("#box_ni").chosen({});
   $(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '#add', function() {
            value2 = $("#box_input").val();
            $("#box_ni").attr("data-placeholder", "Select boxes for intake... ");
            $("#box_ni").append("<option>"+value2+"</option>");
            $("#box_ni").trigger("chosen:updated");
            $("#box_input").val('');
    });
});
```

html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="labelStyle" for="box_ni">Select Your Box(es)</label> <select class="form-control chosen-select" data-placeholder="No new intake to display..." disabled id="box_ni" multiple name="box_ni[]">
      <option value="">
      </option>
    </select>
    <div id="nidstrmessage"></div>
    <div class="servicesHelp">
      Just some example blurb.
    </div>
    <div class="noBrtvBoxes" style="color:white;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this but before I explain how, be aware you `disabled` the `select option`, by this `chosen` not working. You just need to set `selected` attribute when you append new `option`

```js
$("#box_ni").chosen({
  max_selected_options: 3
});

$(document).on('click', '#add', function() {
  value2 = $("#box_input").val();
  $("#box_ni").attr("data-placeholder", "Select boxes for intake... ");
  $("#box_ni").append("<option selected>" + value2 + "</option>");
  $("#box_ni").trigger("chosen:updated");
  $("#box_input").val('');
});
```

```css
#box_ni {
  width: 200px;
}

#add {
  display: block;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.3/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.3/chosen.min.css" />

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="labelStyle" for="box_ni">Select Your Box(es)</label>

  <select class="form-control chosen-select" data-placeholder="No new intake to display..." id="box_ni" multiple name="box_ni[]">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>

  <div id="nidstrmessage"></div>
  <div class="servicesHelp">
    Just some example blurb.
  </div>
  <div class="noBrtvBoxes" style="color:white;"></div>
</div>
<input id="box_input" type="text" value="bingo" />
<a id="add">Click Me!</a>
```

Comment: many thanks for that. But can you explain how I disabled the select option? Thanks

Comment: Why you want to disabled select when you try to add some new option? If you disable it, chosen won't work. @user1532468

Comment: My Question is `where did i disable it`. Also I have `chosen:maxselected` option in my other code and this seems to work from dropdown. Is there a way to restrict the selected items to say 3 using your code. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 here => `disabled id="box_ni"` | Yes I think so there must be a way, let me think I'll update my answer.

Comment: @user1532468 No there is no native way to do this, just need to write some js code.. but better way to use `max_selected_options`

Comment: Yeh sorry. It is disabled on page load then enabled further on. I have done a rough code using count++ but i cannot see way to decrease the counter if a user removes item from list. Thanks

Comment: `value2 = $("#box_input").val();
        var count = $("#box_ni :selected").length;
        $("#counter").html("Total selected boxes for intake: " + '<span style="font-size: 14px; color: white;">' + '( ' + count + ' )' + '</span>').css('color:, black');
          if(count > 2){
              $("#counter").html("No more than 3");
              return false;
          } else {
              count++;
            $("#counter").html("Total selected boxes for intake: " + '<span style="font-size: 14px; color: white;">' + '( ' + count + ' )' + '</span>').css('color:, black');
          }`